# Ajax + Php function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have made a contact form to send emails with an Ajax request, this request call a PHP function from another file. This function is working well but after the calling of this function, every form datas are missing.

HTML :

```
<form method="post" id="formContact">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Formulaire contact de Bicrav'art</legend>
        <div>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Nom Prénom" name="name" id="formName">
            <input type="tel" placeholder="Téléphone" name="tel" id="formTel">
            <input type="email" placeholder="Email" name="email" id="formEmail">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Objet" name="subject" id="formSubject">
        </div>
    <textarea cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Message" name="message" id="formMessage"></textarea>
    <button type="submit" id="formSubmit">Envoyer</button>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

AJAX :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#formContact').submit(function(event) {

    var formData = {
        // 'functionName' : 'contact',
        'name' : $('#formName').val(),
        'email' : $("#formEmail").val(),
        'tel' : $("#formTel").val(),
        'subject' : $("#formSubject").val(),
        'message' : $("#formMessage").val()
    };

    console.log(formData);

    $.ajax({
        url: "includes/functions",
        type: "POST",
        data: {action: 'contact', contactData: formData},
        dataType: 'json',
        encode: true
    })
    .done(function(data){
        console.log(formData);
        console.log(data);

        if(!data.success){
            console.log('EMAIL SEND');
        }else{
            console.log('EMAIL NOT SEND');
        }
    });
    event.preventDefault();
});
});
```

PHP Function :

```
<?php
// error_reporting(E_ALL);
// ini_set("display_errors", 1);

if(isset($_POST['action'])) {
    $action = $_POST['action'];
    switch($action) {
        case 'contact' : sendEmail();
    }
}

// SEND EMAIL
function sendEmail(){
    $data = $_POST['contactData'];
    $data = array();
    if (!empty($_POST['name'])
        && !empty($_POST['email'])
        && !empty($_POST['tel'])
        && !empty($_POST['subject'])
        && !empty($_POST['message']))
    {
        // var_dump($_POST['name']);
        // var_dump($_POST['email']);
        // var_dump($_POST['tel']);
        // var_dump($_POST['subject']);
        // var_dump($_POST['message']);

        $to = '*****@hotmail.fr';
        $content = ''.$_POST['message'].'';
        $subject = 'Nouvelle demande de contact - Bicrav\'Art';
        $from = ''.$_POST['email'].'';

        $uri = 'https://mandrillapp.com/api/1.0/messages/send.json';
        $api_key = '****************';
        $content_text = strip_tags($content);

        $postString = '{
            "key": "' . $api_key . '",
            "message": {
            "html": "' . $content . '",
            "text": "' . $content_text . '",
            "subject": "' . $subject . '",
            "from_email": "' . $from . '",
            "from_name": "' . $from . '",
            "to": [
            {
                "email": "' . $to . '",
                "name": "' . $to . '"
            }
            ],
            "track_opens": true,
            "track_clicks": true,
            "auto_text": true,
            "url_strip_qs": true,
            "preserve_recipients": true
            },
            "async": false
        }';

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $uri);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true );
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postString);
        $result = curl_exec($ch);

        $data['success'] = true;

    }else{
        $data['success'] = false;
    }
    echo json_encode($data);
    }
```

The sendEmail function is working well, but form datas do not pass this

```
if(isset($_POST['action'])) {
$action = $_POST['action'];
switch($action) {
    case 'contact' : sendEmail();
}
}
```

Thx for your help,
Sorry for my bad english

Comment: Can you check in PHP file with `print_r($_POST)` , what it returns?

Comment: i think `$_POST['name']`  should be something like `$_POST['contactData']['name']` as name stored in `contactData` array

Comment: your not using proper way to send your data with jquery ajax you wont get anything on your php page

Comment: Yea, this was'nt the proper way to send my datas, i sent this with one single variable. Php function is working well right now. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is here:

```
$data = $_POST['contactData'];
$data = array();
if (!empty($_POST['name'])
    && !empty($_POST['email'])
    && !empty($_POST['tel'])
    && !empty($_POST['subject'])
    && !empty($_POST['message']))
{
```

This `$_POST['contactData']` is not empty, it contains all your fields.
But you are checking all fields inside `$_POST` instead of `$_POST['contactData']`.

Every field should be:

```
$data = $_POST['contactData'];
$data = array();
if (!empty($_POST['contactData']['name'])
    && !empty($_POST['contactData']['email'])
    && !empty($_POST['contactData']['tel'])
    && !empty($_POST['contactData']['subject'])
    && !empty($_POST['contactData']['message']))
{
```

You can alternatively write in the first row:

```
$_POST = $_POST['contactData'];
$data = array();
if (!empty($_POST['name'])
    && !empty($_POST['email'])
    && !empty($_POST['tel'])
    && !empty($_POST['subject'])
    && !empty($_POST['message']))
{
```

.. and every field match.